# Disable data-autoclose dropdown Foundation just in one menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, zurb-foundation-6

I have a question.

How do I disable autoclose just for dropdown that has a class of `STAY-ACTIVE`

[**Codepen example**](http://codepen.io/thallysondias/pen/jqzjLm)

In the Codepen example above, I want the "Iniciar Sessão" menu item to stay active moving my mouse away.

---

This is my Code:

```
<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu  >
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="button">MENU 1</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="button">MENU 2</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#"> ITEM 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> ITEM 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> ITEM 3 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  

    <li class="STAY-ACTIVE">
        <a href="#" class="button">MENU 3</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#"> ITEM 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> ITEM 2 </a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>     

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="button ">MENU 4</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#"> ITEM 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> ITEM 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> ITEM 3 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> ITEM 4 </a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>     

</ul>
```

if I use the `data-autoclose:false` option all of the `li` are influenced.

I want the `li` with a class of `STAY-ACTIVE` to close when a click occurs outside it and the others to close after they lose focus/the mouse is moved away.

I'm using Foundation 6

If you have any doubts, I'll try to address them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do what you want would be to change the `closingTime` value according to which menu item is active. When you initialize the Foundation plugins on the page, you can target individual elements, instead of everything on the page.

You can use this option to initialize the dropdown menu and also have a reference to it, allowing easy manipulation of certain defaults (like the `closingTime`)

Please see the comments in the JavaScript/jQuery below for an explanation of what I'm doing.

```
//Specify a default closing time, so it can be reset as and when required.
var defaultClosingTime = 500;
var options = {
  "closingTime": defaultClosingTime
};

//Initialize the dropdown menu with a closingTime of 500.
var elem = new Foundation.DropdownMenu($('#dropdown'), options);

//On a mouseover, check if the active item has a class of "STAY-ACTIVE". If it does, update 
//the DropdownMenu element's closingTime to a really large value, so that it remains open.
$('.is-dropdown-submenu-parent').on('mouseover', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('STAY-ACTIVE')) {
    //You can increase this value if you want to give your users more time.
    elem.options.closingTime = 6000000;
  } else {
    if (element.options.closingTime !== defaultClosingTime) {
      //If you hover over one of the other menu items, reset the closingTime to the default.
      elem.options.closingTime = defaultClosingTime
    }
  }
});

$(document).foundation();
```

**[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/yassarikhan786/pen/yOjbVL)**

Comment: uow! Thanks a lot! Works nice!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
$(".dropdown li").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).next("ul").show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).next("ul").hide();
  $(this).next("ul.STAY-ACTIVE").show();
});
$(".STAY-ACTIVE").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
$("body").click(function(){
   $(".STAY-ACTIVE").hide()
});
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: doents works. Because use function from foundation. http://codepen.io/thallysondias/pen/jqzjLm